# How to install vmware tools?

Tags: software-installation, vmware-tools

I installed my Ubuntu in vmware, no I need install vmware tools, I got error:

> Searching for a valid kernel header path...
> The path "" is not valid.
> Would you like to change it?[yes]

In CentOS, I run the following commands to resolve this issue:

```
yum install gcc-c++
yum install kernel-devel
yum install kernel-headers
yum -y update kernel
```

But I don't know how to do in Ubuntu.

I have tried the following commands but nothing changed

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo-get install build-essential linux-header-$(uname -r)
sudo ./vmware-uninstall-tools.pl
sudo ./vmware-config-tools.pl
sudo ./vmware-install.pl
```

**Issue Changed:**

Ran

```
sudo ./vmware-uninstall-tools.pl
```

and deleted the folder of `/etc/vmware-tools`
then I ran

```
 sudo ./vmware-install.pl
```

Now I can successfully install vmware-tools.

After restart, I can see the folder `/mnt/hgfs`, but can't see my shared folder.

Comment: Using the open-vm-tools-desktop package from the distribution as suggested by Pavel Kovalev is now the recommended way, see https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2073803 .

Answer (score 42):

I encountered this problem when upgrading from 12.10 to 13.04.  No matter what I did, the VMware Tools installer couldn't seem to find the headers.  For the record, here's how I installed the headers:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Turns out, the installer is looking for the `version.h` file in under `[kernelsource path]/include/linux/version.h`, it's not there. The location of `version.h` is `[kernelsource path]include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h`

The solution is a symlink:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include/linux/version.h
```

After creating this symlink, I was able to run the VMware Tools installer without a problem.

Comment: the symlink fixed my issue as well

Comment: symlink also did fix the issue on ubuntu 13.04 for me

Comment: +1 for the symlink work around, this also solved it for me.

Answer (score 29):

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

> & then install VM-WARE-TOOLS

Go to  vmware **"VM" tab** to install vmware tools

Plz Keep it in mind when you update Ubuntu ( & the  **kernel version is changed** ) u need to run

`vmware-config-tools.pl`

every time only when kernel is changed

Comment: run vmware-config-tools.pl, got same error message:**Searching for a valid kernel header path... The path "" is not valid. Would you like to change it?**

Comment: are you running it with sudo vmware-config-tools.pl ? , i have check its working properly

Comment: I have run vmware-config-tools.pl,nothing changed.

Comment: +1 for a generic approach (`uname -r`)

Comment: +1 This worked with `VMWare Player` v5.0.1 on `Quantal` as well.

Answer (score 16):

1) Use Install VMWare Tools option in VMWare Client to attach media

2) Update the server

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

3) Create the mount point

```
sudo mkdir -p /media/cdrom
```

4) Mount the ISO

```
sudo mount /dev/cdrom /media/cdrom
```

5) Change Directory

```
cd /media/cdrom
```

6) Copy the tar file to your /tmp directory

```
sudo cp VM*.tar.gz /tmp
```

7) Install Build tools if necessary

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-server build-essential
(for desktop is "sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential")
```

8) Change Directory

```
cd /tmp
```

9) Unmount the ISO

```
sudo umount /media/cdrom
```

10) Expand the tar

```
sudo tar xzvf VM*.tar.gz
```

11) Change Directory

```
cd vmware-tools-distrib
```

12) Create a special directory

```
sudo mkdir /usr/lib64
```

13) Run the Install Script

```
sudo ./vmware-install.pl -d
```

14) Reboot

```
sudo reboot
```

[source](http://ghosttx.com/2012/03/how-to-install-vmware-tools-v4-on-ubuntu-11-10-server/)

Comment: That helped, first one statement didn't worked.

Answer (score 8):

Specify `/lib/modules/3.2.0-24-virtual/build/include` as the path after you installed kernel headers via [One Zero's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/132408/22949).

Answer (score 7):

I've just done this on a VMware hosted Ubuntu Linux 12.04 (32-bit) machine and found I needed to do

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-3.2.0-24-generic-pae
```

As well as having the normal build-essential package installed.

Your mileage will vary in terms of the exact linux-headers package to install I guess. But that worked fine for me.

Comment: Not working.'tom@ubuntu:~/vmware-tools-distrib$ sudo apt-get install linux-headers-3.2.0-24-generic-pae
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
linux-headers-3.2.0-24-generic-pae is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 31 not upgraded.
'

Answer (score 4):

The open source tools for VMWare should work just as well, if you want to try going down that route.

### For Ubuntu 12.04+

```
sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools
```

I believe it handles everything else for you. Just restart the virtual machine and VMWare Player should work without a hitch.

Comment: VM Tools doesn't work after reboot. Are you sure I don't need to additionally activate something?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
sudo apt-cache search *package-name*
```

and your package name Ex:

```
sudo apt-cache search kernel
```

and you will be produced with all the available packages in the repository , find out the one you want and

```
sudo apt-get install *package-name*
```

it . Before doing it update your repository with

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Hi, It's not working.tom@ubuntu:~/vmware-tools-distrib$ sudo apt-get install kernel-devel
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package kernel-devel

Comment: Have you tried with the sudo apt-cache search kernel ? You will be definitely shown up with some search results . My laptop is not available at this moment otherwise i would have posted you with screenshots .....

Comment: What's the meaning of searching? I got lots of results.

Answer (score 2):

Feels like I found an answer (I used it for 17.10 ) and [original answer is here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/985924/copy-paste-not-working-in-vmware/1022430#1022430)

In the terminal window execute this command to remove any previously installed tools:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove open-vm-tools
```

and after that execute this command to add tools:

```
sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools-desktop
```

and a final thing: do not forget to reboot.

It worked very well for me!

Comment: Using packages from the distribution as suggested by this answer is now the recommended way, see https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2073803 .

Answer (score 1):

Also make sure you select the OS correctly in VMWare settings. When the OS is "other", Install VMWare Tools menu is greyed out.

Answer (score 0):

install the .bundle as usual

download this file [PATCH](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pr6m8g0ddheeyuv/vmware_patch_modules.tar.gz)

Extract it in the home directory and delete the old patch flag:

```
sudo rm /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/.patched
```

Then run the patch as usual:

```
sudo ./patch-modules_3.2.0.sh vmware3.2.0.patch
```

Hope that helps.
If it doesnt work try keepin the two patch files and the .bundle setup in home directory.

PS: I found this on the forums of VMWare and it fixed the installation issue for me.

Comment: The patch file is not available in dropbox.