# Resolution on Ubuntu 12.04 VMware

Tags: 12.04, vmware, display-resolution

I just converted a physical machine into a virtual one, I got no trouble except for screen.

Now the VM is using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on VMWare Workstation 12.5 and I can't upgrade it (doing `apt-get upgrade`).

The screen appears to be "Unknown" and the available resolution are:

- 1360x768
- 1280x800
- 1280x768
- 1152x864
- 1024x768
- 800x600

I need to bring it to 1920x1080.
I tried by installing VMware Tools by running the native Vmware's `vmware-install.pl` leaving all defaults, but without luck:
During the installation it writes:

```
Detected X server version 1.11.3

Distribution provided drivers for Xorg X server are used.

Skipping X configuration because X drivers are not included"
```

And after the reboot Vmware says:

> The Virtual machine could not be changed to the selected monitor layout.
>
> If you just added a monitor to the host computer, you must power off and power on the virtual machine to use that monitor.

I tried, as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131351/how-to-install-vmware-tools/132408#132408), to do

> sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)

the output I get is:

> Reading package lists... Done
>
> Building dependency tree
>
> Reading state information... Done
>
> build-essential is already the newest version.
>
> linux-headers-3.2.0-86-generic-pae is already the newest version.
>
> 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 407 not upgraded.

I finally tried another way [found here](http://www.noobslab.com/2012/10/fix-your-unknown-display-problem-in.html?m=1) and it was unlucky too.

> sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
>   out:
>   Reading package lists... Done
>
> Building dependency tree
>
> Reading state information... Done
>
> mesa-utils is already the newest version.
>
> 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 407 not upgraded.

input:

> glxinfo | grep render
>   output:
>   X Error of failed request:  BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)
>
> Major opcode of failed request:  154 (GLX)
>
> Minor opcode of failed request:  19 (X_GLXQueryServerString)
>
> Serial number of failed request:  12
>
> Current serial number in output stream:  12

input:

> glxgears

out put:

> X Error of failed request:  BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)
>
> Major opcode of failed request:  154 (GLX)
>
> Minor opcode of failed request:  19 (X_GLXQueryServerString)
>
> Serial number of failed request:  12
>
> Current serial number in output stream:  12

What else can I try?

Comment: Did you try to reconfigure X ?
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg

Comment: Just tried, I got no output e no effect.

Answer (score 0):

When you first install Ubuntu using VMware, there is a dialogue box new virtual machine wizard you need to select, `customize hardware`. See this screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Now, go to display and select specify monitor setting and select a resolution according to your system. You can see in below picture then save this. 
See this screenshot:

[image: screenshot]