# Copy/paste not working in Vmware

Tags: 16.04, vmware, vmware-tools

I run my Ubuntu in a VMWare virtual machine that is hosted by Win10. Vmware tools is installed.

I can't copy from notepad in Windows and paste into Ubuntu applications. Vice versa works fine. The virtual machine settings for copy/paste - enabled:

[image: settings]

How to enable copy from Windows 10 and paste to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 7):

Feels like I found an answer (I used it for 17.10 )

In the terminal window execute this command to remove any previously installed tools:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove open-vm-tools
```

and after that execute this command to add tools:

```
sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools-desktop
```

and a final thing: do not forget to reboot.

It worked very well for me!

Comment: I dit it. It works... but copy-past file doesn't work from host(Debian 10) to guest(Debian 10). Copy-past files works only from guest to host. Any ideas?